# How to evaluate series based on recurrence equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I've come across this problem in an advanced high school worksheet, but I don't know the origin of the problem.

Given the sequence $(x_n)_{\mathbb{N}}$

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x_{1}=1 \\
x_{n+1}=\sqrt{x_{n}(x_{n}+1)(x_{n}+2)(x_{n}+3)+1} , n\ge2
\end{array}
\right.
$$

How to evaluate the series

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x_{k}+2}
$$

Here's what I got:

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x_{n}(x_{n}+1)(x_{n}+2)(x_{n}+3)+1} & = \sqrt{(x_{n}^2+3x_{n}+1)^2} \\
& = |x_{n}^2+3x_{n}+1|
\end{align}
$$

As $x_1=1 > 0 $, $x_{n}^2+3x_{n}+1$ will be positive for all $n \ge 2$ . Thus:

$$
x_{n+1}=x_n^2+3x_{n}+1
$$

This is not good. The relation is neither linear nor homogeneous.

I also have no idea on how to evaluate the series. I can show that it converges comparing it to $\sum \frac{1}{k^2}$, but I can not think on how to evaluate it.

A quick program gives me these values for $x_n$ and for the partial sum $S_n$:

```
x[1]=1.0000000000
S[1]=0.3333333333
x[2]=5.0000000000
S[2]=0.4761904762
x[3]=41.0000000000
S[3]=0.4994462901
x[4]=1805.0000000000
S[4]=0.4999996936
x[5]=3263441.0000000000
S[5]=0.5000000000
x[6]=10650056950805.0000000000
S[6]=0.5000000000
x[7]=113423713055421845118910464.0000000000
S[7]=0.5000000000
x[8]=12864938683278672079501004830742670366487445279604736.0000000000
S[8]=0.5000000000
x[9]=165506647324519962593059552590935669575232079131271199714697991661245368701786157147328071653890281439232.0000000000
S[9]=0.5000000000
x[10]=27392450308603031764480870527381648752347551731785263407975564098191394906718645585260110781473383370045001182698658109358654445966317201271160135904061763917073783821325868369071377919640132022498004014465024.0000000000
S[10]=0.5000000000
```

So if I were to guess, I would say that $\sum \frac{1}{x_{n}+2} = 1/2$

I would appreciate any help finding a general expression for $x_n$ so I can go on to solving the series as usual.

Comment: If you $\color{green}{\checkmark}$, consider also $\color{green}{\uparrow}$. :) Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein, I upvoted it, but it won't be displayed until I have a higher rep. :(

Comment: Thanks, no problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the first few partial sums, it's easy to conjecture that the general form of the $n$th partial sum is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{x_k+2}}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{x_k+2}}.
$$
To show that, notice that $x_{n+1}+1=(x_n+1)(x_n+2)$, so
$$
\frac{1}{x_n+2}=\frac{x_n+1}{x_{n+1}+1},
$$
so that
$$
\frac{1}{2}\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{x_k+2}}=\frac{x_1+1}{2(x_{n+1}+1)}=\frac{1}{x_{n+1}+1}.
$$
This makes the inductive step pretty easy:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}{\frac{1}{x_k+2}}=\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{x_{n+1}+1}\right)+\frac{1}{x_{n+1}+2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{(x_{n+1}+1)(x_{n+1}+2)}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{x_{n+2}+1}.
$$

*Update:* Also, take a look at the OEIS page for [A000058](https://oeis.org/A000058). These are the denominators $x_n+2$.